# proftpd conf on debian

Tags: debian, ftp, proftpd

Iam new to linux / debian

Im trying to configure an ftp server in debian using proftpd.

I installed the package A user is created when it is installed I put a password to this user and it is working fine. Im trying to let local users with local passwords in the server to have ftp access but without luck so far What should I do to allow a specific group to have a ftp access. Then I tried using sftp, it is working for the root user but not for any other local user

Im also trying to open a specific directory in the web browser using http:/ipaddress/directoryneeded but it is telling me forbidden so also without luck

I appreciate your help and ready for any other detail needed from me

Answer (score 0):

Please try adding the below command which will be helpful to provide full access to the local user,

mkdir  /home/ftp_user/www_dev

mount  --bind  /var/www/dev/  /home/ftp_user/www_dev

Comment: Hello friend. First of all thank you very much for your reply, I tried what you said but still it is not working with me. A local user is not able to login to ftp and I have no idea why. If you want any screenshot of some conf Im ready I dont know where Im going wrong